# YII2 post logout link on non YII2 page

Tags: yii2

I've created a YII2 site I want to allow the user to logout, not on a page in the YII2 folder.  In YII2 I'm using the nav component, so the logout part of the layout looks like this

```
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right player-page'],
    'encodeLabels' => false,
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Logout',
            'items' => [
                [
                    'label' => 'Sign out (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                    'url' => ['/site/logout'],
                    'template' => '<a href="{url}" data-method="post">{label}</a>',
                    'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

I've tried Javascript.  This is the latest one.

```
 window.onload=function() {
   document.getElementById("logout").onclick=function() {
     var myForm = document.createElement("form");
     myForm.action='http://151.236.49.237/~aceify1/booking/site/logout';// the href of the link
     myForm.target="myFrame";
     myForm.method="POST";
     document.body.appendChild(myForm);
     myForm.submit();
     return false; // cancel the actual link
   }
 }
```

But it just says internal server error on the YII2 logout URL.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: It might be a good idea to check debug toolbar, app.log or apache's error.log for actual error.

Comment: _csrf token must be sent along with POST request.

Comment: what is the error code ? and do you want to logout from site from other urls? such your domain is domain.com and you want logout with url in example.com?

Comment: Michal - I checked the error_log and there is an error but it's not useful.  I'm guessing the important part is this "exception 'yii\web\BadRequestHttpException' with message 'Unable to verify your data submission.'" which is probably linke to what Manu said.

ttrasn - It's from the same domain, so the yii is like domain.com/subsite and the page I want to have the logoug link is in the root domain.

I'm going to create a YII2 page that just has a logout link and iframe/embed that.  Thanks for the input and if anyone has any ideas that are slicker than an iframe, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: If message is some like  'Unable to verify your data submission.'  then needed disable the CSRF validation...

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the CSRF validation check for the logout function. Add this to your controller, or modify your already existing beforeAction() as required

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{            
    if ($action->id == 'logout') {
         $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: Or inside some action like logoutAction write $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;

Comment: Thanks for this.  In the end I did what I mentioned in my previous comment and created a page just with the link in and iframed it, with a few design tweaks it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

You just convert it to simple link without **data-method='POST'**

and remove below line form **behaviors** function of **SiteController**

```
'logout' => ['post'],
```